# Including multiple files with C++

Tags: c++, header-files

This week my class took a spin and is teaching material not found in the book. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, the project is to take 5 numbers from the keyboard and get the average, but I have to use functions with a `.h` header file and corresponding `.cpp` file to receive credit. This is what I have so far

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "average.h"

using namespace std;

const int numbersinput=5;

int main ()
{
  int numbers,sum,avg;

  cout << "Hello, please enter 5 numbers you would like to see the average for." << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i != numbersinput; ++i)
  {
    cin >> numbers;

    sum += numbers;
  }

  int average(int sum);
  cout << avg;

  system ("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

The .h headerfile named average.h

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int average(int);
```

and the other .cpp file named average.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "average.h"

using namespace std;

const int numbersinput=5;
int avg;

int average(int sum)
{
  avg = sum /numbersinput;
  return avg;
}
```

I can get a successful build, but I get this error after I enter the first number and press enter.

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'sum' is being used without
>   being initialized.

What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to initialize sum to `0` before you start adding to it with `+=`:

So instead of `int numbers,sum,avg;`
You will have `int sum = 0;` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
int numbers,sum,avg;
```

To:

```
int numbers=0;
int sum=0;
int avg=0;
```

This gives the variables values- before they are initialized (given a value) they are undefined, which means that they could equal any value. By initializing them, you are giving them a number to add to when you make the sum.

Edit these lines:

```
int average(int sum);

cout << avg;
```

To:

```
cout << average(sum);
```

The function declaration for `int average(int sum)` is not called in the same way as it is declared. The ints are unnecessary. In my edited code, you can see that the returned value (`average`)is printed out, instead of being left without being used.

Also, as a general tip, try not to give variables the same name. Try to make the function variable `sum` be called `sumToAverage` or instead make the `sum` in `main` be called `total`. It is a good idea to pick variable names that are different, so you won't get confused.

Comment: Thank you everyone, its been a long week, I i was missing simple mistakes.

Comment: No problem! Everyone makes mistakes :)

Comment: @geno84 I'd also recommend looking at Sean's answer. He catches some other important things.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying :

```
sum += numbers
```

But you haven't initialized `sum`, so it will have some random value that's on the stack. Change your declaration of `sum` to:

```
int sum = 0;
```

Also, you're using global variables to pass information to functions, which isn't a good idea. Get rid of the `avg` variable and change `average` to:

```
int average(int sum, int numberofvalues)
{
  int avg = sum / numberofvalues;
  return avg;
}
```

You're also re-declared `average` in the body of main, which you don't need to do as it's in the header. Then, you can get the average in main by saying:

```
int avg = average(sum, numbersinput);
```

Now, `main` will look like this:

```
int main ()
{
 int sum=0;

 cout << "Hello, please enter 5 numbers you would like to see the average for." << endl;

 for (int i = 0; i != numbersinput; ++i)
 {
   int number;
   cin >> number;

   sum += number;
 }


 int avg = average(sum, numbersinput);

 cout << avg;    

 system ("PAUSE");

 return 0;
}
```

Oh, and don't put `using namespace std` in header files!

Comment: My instructor stated that "You always need the namespace command in every file" What is the significance and why shouldn't I put using namespace st in header files?

Comment: Your instructor is wrong, you should never put it into header files. The reason is that if introduces all the `std` classes that you include. If I want a `std` class I'll ask for it. It's fine to put it into .cpp files as that only pollutes your scope, but putting it into a header file pollutes the scope of everyone who includes your header.